# How to set the name of columns in the tree view through tree.plot_tree?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to draw a tree through sklearn lib tree, but the problem is that column indexes are written in the picture.

`tree.plot_tree(clf_decision)`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make use of [`feature_names` and `class_names` parameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0).fit(iris.data, iris.target)


tree.plot_tree(clf, feature_names=iris.feature_names, class_names=iris.target_names)
```

[image]